# Django REST Framework - Separate permissions per methods

Tags: python, django, rest, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am writing an API using Django REST Framework and I am wondering if can specify permissions per method when using class based views.

[Reading the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) I see that is quite easy to do if you are writing function based views, just using the `@permission_classes` decorator over the function of the views you want to protect with permissions. However, I don't see a way to do the same when using CBVs with the `APIView` class, because then I specify the permissions for the full class with the `permission_classes` attribute, but that will be applied then to all class methods (`get`, `post`, `put`...).

So, is it possible to have the API views written with CBVs and also specify different permissions for each method of a view class?

Comment: How about you create a separate view for each one? Or you could overwrite the get/post/put methods in your view and write your own permissions.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Permissions are applied to the entire View class, but you can take into account aspects of the request (like the method such as GET or POST) in your authorization decision.

See the built-in `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` as an example:

```
SAFE_METHODS = ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']

class IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    """
    The request is authenticated as a user, or is a read-only request.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (request.method in SAFE_METHODS or
            request.user and
            request.user.is_authenticated()):
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks, Kevin. Your answer was perfect. There is the `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` permission class, which can use `SAFE_METHODS`.

Comment: Very nice, will also work for a POST - only API, say for creation of leads by third - party affiliates, but to prevent the listing of the entire lead list?

Comment: In Django 3+ (don't know about previous versions), `request.user.is_authenticated()` is actually `request.user.is_authenticated`. `is_authenticated` is not (any more?) a method but a bool

Comment: You can `from rest_framework.permissions import SAFE_METHODS` rather than re-defining `SAFE_METHODS` yourself.

Answer (score 55):

I've come across the same problem when using CBV's, as i have fairly complex permissions logic depending on the request method.

The solution i came up with was to use the third party 'rest_condition' app listed at the bottom of this page

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions

https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition

I just split the permissions flow logic so that each branch will run, depending on the request method.

```
from rest_condition import And, Or, Not

class MyClassBasedView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [Or(And(IsReadOnlyRequest, IsAllowedRetrieveThis, IsAllowedRetrieveThat),
                             And(IsPostRequest, IsAllowedToCreateThis, ...),
                             And(IsPutPatchRequest, ...),
                             And(IsDeleteRequest, ...)]
```

So the 'Or' determines which branch of the permissions should run depending on the request method and the 'And' wraps the permissions relating to the accepted request method, so all must pass for permission to be granted. You can also mix 'Or', 'And' and 'Not' within each flow to create even more complex permissions.

The permission classes to run each branch simply look like this,

```
class IsReadyOnlyRequest(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS


class IsPostRequest(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method == "POST"


... #You get the idea
```

Comment: Feel free to also try this: https://github.com/Pithikos/rest-framework-roles

Comment: DRF has added functionality similar to this:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy
"Provided they inherit from rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission, permissions can be composed using standard Python bitwise operators ... Note: t supports & (and), | (or) and ~ (not)."
So you can write permissions like `permission_classes = [IsAlienFromSpace & IsFriendly, IsAuthenticated | ReadOnly]`

Answer (score 22):

***Update 30 March 2020***: My original solution only patched **object** permissions, not request permissions. I've included an update below to make this work with request permissions as well.

I know this is an old question but I recently ran into the same problem and wanted to share my solution (since the accepted answer wasn't quite what I needed). @GDorn's answer put me on the right track, but it only works with `ViewSet`s because of the `self.action`

I've solved it creating my own decorator:

```py
def method_permission_classes(classes):
    def decorator(func):
        def decorated_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.permission_classes = classes
            # this call is needed for request permissions
            self.check_permissions(self.request)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_func
    return decorator
```

Instead of setting the `permission_classes` property on the function, like the built-in decorator does, my decorator wraps the call and sets the permission classes on the view instance that is being called. This way, the normal `get_permissions()` doesn't need any changes, since that simply relies on `self.permission_classes`.

To work with request permissions, we do need to call `check_permission()` from the decorator, because the it's orginally called in `initial()` so before the `permission_classes` property is patched.

**Note** The permissions set through the decorator are the only ones called for *object* permissions, but for request permissions they are *in addition* to the class wide permissions, because those are always checked before the request method is even called. If you want to specify all permissions per method only, set `permission_classes = []` on the class.

Example use case:

```py
from rest_framework import views, permissions

class MyView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)  # used for default APIView endpoints
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer


    @method_permission_classes((permissions.IsOwnerOfObject,))  # in addition to IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    def delete(self, request, id):
        instance = self.get_object()  # ...
```

Hope this helps someone running into the same problem!

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this problem and really wanted to use the `@permission_classes` decorator to mark some custom view methods with specific permissions.  I ended up coming up with a mixin:

```
class PermissionsPerMethodMixin(object):
    def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Allows overriding default permissions with @permission_classes
        """
        view = getattr(self, self.action)
        if hasattr(view, 'permission_classes'):
            return [permission_class() for permission_class in view.permission_classes]
        return super().get_permissions()
```

An example use case:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action, permission_classes  # other imports elided

class MyViewset(PermissionsPerMethodMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)  # used for default ViewSet endpoints
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))  # overrides IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    def search(self, request):
        return do_search(request)  # ...
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue.

I wanted to allow unauthenticated POSTs but disallow unauthenticated GETs.

An unauthenticated member of the public can submit an item but only an authenticated admin user can retrieve the list of items submitted.

So I built a custom permission class - `UnauthenticatedPost` - for the POST and then set the list of permission clases to be `IsAuthentictaed` or `UnauthenticatedPost`.

Note I only allow gets and posts by setting the allowable methods with `http_method_names = ['get', 'post']`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAuthenticated
from MyAPI.serializers import MyAPISerializer
from MyAPI.models import MyAPI


class UnauthenticatedPost(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in ['POST']


class MyAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated|UnauthenticatedPost]
    queryset = MyAPI.objects.all().order_by('-TimeSubmitted')
    serializer_class = MyAPISerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use `ViewSet`s or `ModelViewSet`s, I think overwriting `get_permissions` will do the trick.
Take a look at how [djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/35e5a5e75127d7270ab8f7bb13c4f7d0c0ec5a7b/djoser/views.py#L68-L93) handles this.

Example:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = settings.PERMISSIONS.user  # default

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "activation":  # per action
            self.permission_classes = settings.PERMISSIONS.activation
        return super().get_permissions()

    @action(["post"], detail=False)  # action
    def activation(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Answer (score 6):

This question is about `APIView` instances, but for anyone landing here looking for a per-method permissions override using the `@action` decorator within `ViewSets`:

```py
class SandwichViewSet(ModelViewSet):
  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

  @action(..., permission_classes=[CanSeeIngredients])
  def retrieve__ingredients(self, request):
    ...
```

Comment: Does this work? I could not make it work, it simply ignores. I debugged, and it does override permissions classes, but my endpoint is still can be reached by another user. Should I somehow call super, or something else? @Adam

Comment: Ok, It does work. You need to call self.get_object() though, to trigger permission.

Answer (score 2):

We're having the same kind of challenges when it comes to having different permissions for GET, PUT and POST, and have solved this using a customized permission-class:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class HasRequiredPermissionForMethod(permissions.BasePermission):
    get_permission_required = None
    put_permission_required = None
    post_permission_required = None

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        permission_required_name = f'{request.method.lower()}_permission_required'
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        if not hasattr(view, permission_required_name):
            view_name = view.__class__.__name__
            self.message = f'IMPLEMENTATION ERROR: Please add the {permission_required_name} variable in the API view class: {view_name}.'
            return False

        permission_required = getattr(view, permission_required_name)
        if not request.user.has_perm(permission_required):
            self.message = f'Access denied. You need the {permission_required} permission to access this service with {request.method}.'
            return False

        return True
```

We use this in our API's like this:

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [HasRequiredPermissionForMethod]
    get_permission_required = 'permission_to_read_this'
    put_permission_required = 'permission_to_update_this'
    post_permission_required = 'permission_to_create_this'

    def get(self, request):
        # impl get

    def put(self, request):
        # impl put

    def post(self, request):
        # impl post
```

Answer (score 1):

I write my solution with hope that it helps someone.
As much as I understand, There are two ways to handle permissions in APIView class

1. Statically assign a proper `Permission` classes  to `APIView.permission_classes` (like extend `BasePermission`)
2. Dynamically decide `Permission` instances in `APIView` (override `APIView.get_permission()`)

`APIView` checks permissions returned from `.get_permission()`.
And `.get_permission()` instantiates `Permission`s from `.permission_classes`.

In my situation, Only I needed a predefined `Permission` but depending on method.
So I chose latter approach.

```
class TokenView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    
    // return instances of Permission classes
    def get_permissions(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method in ['DELETE']:
            return [IsAuthenticated()]
        else:
            return []

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data["username"]
        password = request.data["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"token": token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        user.auth_token.delete()
        return Response({"success", status.HTTP_200_OK})
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I've made for that a mixin. You just have to inherit this mixin.

```
class FooViewSet(ModelViewSet, PermissionByAction):

    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    permission_classes_by_action = {
        'create': [IsAuthenticated],
        'list': [AllowAny],
        'retrieve': [AllowAny],
        'destroy': [IsOwner | IsAdmin,],
    }
```

This is a mixin:

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
class PermissionByAction(object):

    permission_classes_by_action : dict = {
        'create': api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES,
        'list': api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES,
        'retrieve': api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES,
        'destroy': api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES,
    }

    def get_permissions(self):
        permission_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES
    
        if self.action == "list":
            permission_classes = self.permission_classes_by_action['list']
        
        elif self.action == "create":
            permission_classes = self.permission_classes_by_action['create']
        
        elif self.action == "retrieve":
            permission_classes = self.permission_classes_by_action['retrieve']
        
        elif self.action == "destroy":
            permission_classes = self.permission_classes_by_action['destroy']

        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the permissions explicitly, or annotate with your custom method.
Once the request entered into method, there's no way that the permission will be checked from the global value of permission classes. You need a wrapper condition like this.

```
class TestView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer


    def perms_wrapper(self, request, permissions, view):
        for _ in permissions:
            obj = _()
            if not obj.has_permission(request, view):
                return False
        return True

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated, ]
        if self.perms_wrapper(request, self.permission_classes, super):
            test_qs = TestModel.objects.all()
            serializer = TestSerializer(test_qs, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'detail' : 'permissions denied'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```