# Dynamically Change Authentication Classes Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, request, django-rest-framework

I understand that we can set up authentication classes in class based viewsets like this:

```
class ExampleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
```

However, **is there a way to dynamically change the authentication class based on the request method?** I tried overriding this function in my `ExampleViewSet`:

```
def get_authenticators(self): # Found in 
    if self.request.method == "POST":
        authentication_classes.append(authentication.MyCustomAuthentication)
    return authentication_classes
```

However, django rest does not have the `request` object setup at this point:

```
'ExampleViewSet' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Note: not real variable names - just for example purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **detail_route** decorator from rest_framework like this for getting requests,
detail_route can be used to define post as well as get,options or delete options
So,the updated code should be like :

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class ExampleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    @detail_route(methods=['post','get'])
    def get_authenticators(self, request, **kwargs): # Found in 
        if request.method == "POST":
            authentication_classes.append(authentication.MyCustomAuthentication)
        return authentication_classes
```

For further reading,[Read from here.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Comment: using django 1.11 with python3 it says get_authentictors is expecting 2 arguments but only received one (which makes sense since this override specifies self and request as positional args).

I think for my use case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773869/django-rest-framework-separate-permissions-per-methods seems to get me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous answer, it works on django 1.10

```
@detail_route(methods=['post', 'get'])
def get_authenticators(self):
    if self.request.method == "GET":
        self.authentication_classes = [CustomAuthenticationClass]
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
```